# Disable multimedia scanning in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-management, media

Whenever I open a folder with more than just a few pictures or videos, Windows 7 becomes slow and takes several minutes to scan every single file for media information such as resolution. Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try right-clicking on the folder, choose Properties, Customize tab, and set "Optimize this folder for:" to "General items".

If this works, you might consider opening Organize / Folder and search options, View tab, and click on "Apply to Folders" so all folders will be displayed this way.

Still in Folder and search options, you might go to the General tab, and change Tasks to "Use Windows classic folders".

Comment: On top of setting it to General items, you may want to set `Also apply this template to all subfolders`.  I have this set for my top level Folder on my External Drive.  In folder options `Always show icons, never thumbnails`.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible under Windows 7

You need to disable the appropriate property handlers for multimedia files.

Rename (all relevant) registry keys under:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertyHandlers...

Credit goes to [Daniel Martín](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/551eed27-6aaa-4ee2-8ab7-e843ae103c50/disable-file-contents-scanning-not-thumbnail-in-explorer-view-for-ts-files?forum=w7itproui)